# как установить cuda 11.1 и nvidia driver 450

Tags: драйвер, cuda

ставлю cuda 11.1 он автоматом подтягивает драйвер 455 версии, как использовать cuda v 11.1 и nvidia_driver_450?

Comment: Windows? Mac OS X? Linux? Какой инсталлятор? Откуда брали? Как ставили?